# Pandas create new columns based on column headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create several new columns in a pandas dataframe that merge portions of multiple other columns based on year (yet another column) and column headers. The layout of the dataframe currently is:

| 2000_A1 | 2000_A2 | 2001_A1 | 2001_A2 | Year | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 8 | 0 | 3 | 2000 | 43.65 | -76.26 |
| 3 | 8 | 9 | 4 | 2000 | 43.66 | -76.26 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 2000 | 43.67 | -76.26 |
| 4 | 6 | 5 | 1 | 2001 | 43.68 | -76.26 |
| 7 | 8 | 2 | 0 | 2001 | 43.69 | -76.26 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 2001 | 43.70 | -76.26 |

I would like to create a dataframe that has two new columns (A1 and A2) that combine values based on year, as long as the year matches the column header. Originally, these were two separate dataframes that I merged (`pd.merge()`) based on coordinates (lat/long), which is why they're organized in different manners. Ideally, the new dataframe would look like this:

| 2000_A1 | 2000_A2 | 2001_A1 | 2001_A2 | Year | A1 | A2 | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 8 | 0 | 3 | 2000 | 2 | 8 | 43.65 | -76.26 |
| 3 | 8 | 9 | 4 | 2000 | 3 | 8 | 43.66 | -76.26 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 2000 | 3 | 2 | 43.67 | -76.26 |
| 4 | 6 | 5 | 1 | 2001 | 5 | 1 | 43.68 | -76.26 |
| 7 | 8 | 2 | 0 | 2001 | 2 | 0 | 43.69 | -76.26 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 2001 | 1 | 1 | 43.70 | -76.26 |

If possible, I would like to use a for loop to create these new columns - in my actual dataset, I have about 20 years and either 7 or 9 'A's for each year, so some sort of iterative loop would be great. I'm new to python and struggling to figure out how to approach this, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and [`.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), optionally with `merge` to preserve your original `{year}_A{n}` columns. This will be likely much faster than an iterative solution (including things along the lines of `.apply`)

```
ff = df.copy()  # we will use this later
# split your variable column(s) into an identifier and value column
df = df.melt(id_vars=["Year", "Latitude", "Longitude"])
# parse the parts of {year}_A{n}
parts = df.variable.str.split("_")
df["var_year"] = parts.str[0].astype(int)
df["var_kind"] = parts.str[1]
df = df[df.var_year == df.Year] # use your filtering criteria
ident = ["Year", "Latitude", "Longitude"]
# pivot the frame to get A{n} columns
df = df.pivot(ident, columns="var_kind", values="value")
df = df.reset_index()
df = pd.merge(ff, df, on=ident)  # retain original {year}_A{n}
```

|  | 2000_A1 | 2000_A2 | 2001_A1 | 2001_A2 | Year | Latitude | Longitude | A1 | A2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 8 | 0 | 3 | 2000 | 43.65 | -76.26 | 2 | 8 |
| 1 | 3 | 8 | 9 | 4 | 2000 | 43.66 | -76.26 | 3 | 8 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 2000 | 43.67 | -76.26 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 6 | 5 | 1 | 2001 | 43.68 | -76.26 | 5 | 1 |
| 4 | 7 | 8 | 2 | 0 | 2001 | 43.69 | -76.26 | 2 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 2001 | 43.7 | -76.26 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: That worked beautifully, thank you so much!! I ended up using `pivot_table()` rather than `pivot()` because I had duplicate values, but it seems to have worked well.

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to reshape the data, before merging back to `df`:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

cols = ['Year', 'Latitude', 'Longitude']

temp = (df.pivot_longer(index = cols, 
                        names_to = ['year', '.value'],  
                        names_sep='_')
          .astype({'year':int})
          .query('Year==year')
          .drop(columns='year')
       )

df.merge(temp, on=cols)

   2000_A1  2000_A2  2001_A1  2001_A2  Year  Latitude  Longitude  A1  A2
0        2        8        0        3  2000     43.65     -76.26   2   8
1        3        8        9        4  2000     43.66     -76.26   3   8
2        3        2        5        3  2000     43.67     -76.26   3   2
3        4        6        5        1  2001     43.68     -76.26   5   1
4        7        8        2        0  2001     43.69     -76.26   2   0
5        1        3        1        1  2001     43.70     -76.26   1   1
```

Another option, is a bit more involved, but *may* help with speed, as it tries to not increase the number of rows:

```py
cols = ['Year', 'Latitude', 'Longitude']
temp = df.set_index(cols)
temp.columns = temp.columns.str.split('_', expand = True)
temp.columns.names = ['year', 'letters']
temp = temp.unstack('Year')
# keep columns where Year == year
bools = temp.columns.get_level_values('year').astype(int) == temp.columns.get_level_values('Year')
temp = temp.loc[:, bools].stack('Year')
temp = temp['2000'].fillna(temp['2001'])
df.merge(temp.reset_index(), on=cols)

   2000_A1  2000_A2  2001_A1  2001_A2  Year  Latitude  Longitude   A1   A2
0        2        8        0        3  2000     43.65     -76.26  2.0  8.0
1        3        8        9        4  2000     43.66     -76.26  3.0  8.0
2        3        2        5        3  2000     43.67     -76.26  3.0  2.0
3        4        6        5        1  2001     43.68     -76.26  5.0  1.0
4        7        8        2        0  2001     43.69     -76.26  2.0  0.0
5        1        3        1        1  2001     43.70     -76.26  1.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `pd.apply` on the whole line, catching the desired year to build the column name.

```py
def get_entries(line, new_entry="A1"):
    year = line.year
    used_feature = f"{year}_{new_entry}"
    return line[used_feature]

df["A1"] = df.apply(lambda line : get_entries(line, "A1"), axis=1)
df["A2"] = df.apply(lambda line : get_entries(line, "A2"), axis=1)
```